# Changing displayed Object based on selection

Tags: javascript, html

I haven't been able to find anything specific to this case. Im trying to change the displayed html object based on the selection from a drop down menu.

So far I have:

```
<div class="card-body"></div>
<object id="dategraph" data="assets/img/date_manual_interventions_prefix.html"></object>
<select id="DateGraphList">
        <option value="assets/img/date_manual_interventions_prefix.html">
            Date Graph - Manual Interventions per 1000Mb - SL
        </option>
        <option value="assets/img/date_manual_interventions_prefix_v.html">
            Date Graph - Manual Interventions per 1000Mb - DL
        </option>
        <option value="assets/img/date_manual_interventions_prefix_full.html">
            Date Graph - Manual Interventions per 1000Mb - FN
        </option>
</select>
```

With the js script for this being:

```
function setCar() {
    var obj = document.getElementById("dategraph");
    obj.data = this.value;
    return false;
}
document.getElementById("DateGraphList").onchange = setCar;
```

Could some one point out where i'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried: `obj.setAttribute('data', this.value)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `data` attribute of the [`<object>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) by using [`Element.setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute).

> ***data***
>
> > *The address of the resource as a valid URL. At least one of **data** and **type** must be defined.*

**Note:** Don't forget to set the [content type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types) as stated above.

```html
<object
  id="dategraph"
  type="text/html"
  data="assets/img/date_manual_interventions_prefix.html">
</object>
```

```js
function setCar(e) {
  const obj = document.querySelector('#dategraph');
  obj.setAttribute('data', e.target.value);
}

document.querySelector('#DateGraphList').addEventListener('change', setCar);
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Polywhirl,
I've given your solution a go and sadly there's no change, nothing is updating.

Comment: I was wrong!
I popped the above into a <script> and it works. Thanks a ton!